# MVC3 Razor Execution order

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I read an article a while back which said that the execution order in Razor is different than webforms. Could someone please point me to an article or explain what is different in the execution order?

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: Execution order of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although written for MVC3 Preview 1, this article discusses the execution order in the Razor view engine: http://mvcdev.com/differences-between-asp-net-razor-and-web-forms-view-engines/

Comment: Here is a cached version of the original article: http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=execution+order+in+the+Razor+view+engine&d=4761049014211129&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=f948d55c,6a5ed000